# Minimum distance of intersection between two spheres along a specified vector

Tags: geometry, vectors, spheres, collision-detection

I have two spheres $(S_1, S_2)$ within a Cartesian space defined by their centroids $(p_1,p_2)$ and their radii $(r_1,r_2)$. $p_1$ is located at the origin of the coordinate frame such that $x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 = r_1^2$. $p_2$ is located at the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ such that $(x_2 - x_0)^2 + (y_2 - y_0)^2 + (z_2 - z_0)^2 = r_2^2$. $S_2$ lies in the path of $S_1$ as it is translated along the unit vector $V$ $=$ $[0$ $0$ $-1]$. Note that the centroids of the spheres are not coincident along the vector $V$ (see the attached figure), otherwise the solution would be trivial.

I am trying to determine the translation $p_1 - t$ at which $S_1$ will 'collide' (i.e. intersect) with $S_2$ (see the linked image). I am happy to use a solution that assumes that $V$ is aligned to the coordinate axis (i.e. my example above) rather than any arbitrary vector. I know that the equivalent problem in two dimensions can be solved as follows

$d = \min(p_y \pm \sqrt{(r_1+r_2)^2 - p_x^2})$, where $p_x = x_1 - x_0$, $p_y = y_1 - y_0$ and $d$ is the minimum distance along $V$ that $S_1$ intersects with $S_2$

[image: sphere-sphere collision]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Find the point where the distances between the two centers is $r_1 + r_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parametrize the center of the second sphere along the translation vector as $t$, for example
$$\vec{c} = \vec{c}_0 + t \vec{c}_V$$
and solve for $t$ in
$$\lVert \vec{c} \rVert = r_1 + r_2$$
Typically, it is easier to solve for the squared distance, i.e.
$$\lVert \vec{c} \rVert^2 = \left(r_1 + r_2\right)^2$$
which is allowed because both sides are nonnegative anyway.

If we assume $\vec{c}_0 = (x_0 , y_0 , z_0)$ and $\vec{c}_V = (0, 0, 1)$, then
$$\lVert \vec{c} \rVert^2 = x_0^2 + y_0^2 + (z_0 + t)^2$$
and therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
x_0^2 + y_0^2 + (z_0 + t)^2 &= (r_1 + r_2)^2 \\
t^2 + 2 z_0 t + x_0^2 + y_0^2 - (r_1 + r_2)^2 &= 0 \\
t &= - z_0 \pm \sqrt{ (r_1 + r_2)^2 - x_0^2 - y_0^2 } \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks for that!